# An Easy Calculation?

Tags: finance

This should be easy. I've been assured that this is correct, but I don't see how.

> $\$40,000$ plus a $\$200.00$ administrative fee plus $3\%$ for four months on $\$40,200 = \$40,602$.

I think it should be 
$40,000 + 200 + (0.03 \times 40,200 \times 4) = 45,024$
Who is right?

Comment: Most probably, 3% is the *annual* percentage, not monthly.

Comment: also rates are exponentiated if not simple.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\frac{40602}{40200}=1.01,$$

corresponding to $4\cdot\dfrac{3}{12}\%$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $1.03^{4/12}\approx1.00990$?

Comment: Many thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Servaes it simply shows it to be APR not APY.

Comment: @Servaes: using monthly compound interests would yield the value $40598.04\cdots$. Given the accuracy of the data, we obviously have simple interests. We have to infer from the loose question.

Comment: wrong monthly compounding gives 40603.51 ...

Comment: Thank you all for correcting me.

Comment: `40200*(1+(3/1200))^4
%2 = 5197249281801/128000000`  `%*1.
%3 = 40603.51001407031250000000000`  it's stated nowhere therefore we can't assume.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: the information we have is $3\%$, presumably yearly. Which can be understood as $0.25\%$ monthly (simple interest) or $1.03^{1/12}-1=0.24662\cdots\%$ monthly (compound interest). One can also understand $0.25\%$ monthly (compound interest, $3.0416\cdots\%$ yearly) but this is not really logical. Given the figures, how can one doubt $40200\times 1.01$ ??

Comment: They are asking which is correct, not if it is correct ...

Comment: I neglected to add that it is annual percentage.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: $(1+3\%/12)^{12}\ne1+3\%$. You should know that.

Comment: I do but that's how compounding goes if given APR. Otherwise you'd be wrong as APY gives a different rate.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: all three interpretations are possible. There is no doubt on the one that fits.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining one of the comments a bit more...
$3\%$ is the annual rate. Since we only have 4 months it is
$40,000 + 200 + (0.03 \times 40,200 \times 4/12) = 40,602 $

where $4/12$ is there because we only care about 4 out of the 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 3% is the annual rate. So, because we only have 4 months we get 4/12 or 1/3 of the year so the equation would be:

40,000+200+(0.03×40,200×1/3)=40,602

I hope this helped you understand this at least a little bit more.